# How to run a Python Discord bot on a cPanel (o2switch)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I started to host my Discord bot on a cPanel (o2switch), but I don't know how to run the bot. I have to define an entry point for my app, but I don't know what it should be.
I tried to set it as a function that just returns `"Launched!"`, but that doesn't work.

```py
# imports

def application():
    return "Launched!"

# bot code
```

Does anyone know what code should I add for my bot runs?

---

EDIT: Added "runner" thing. The bot still doesn't launch, but I have this log:

```
App 16078 output: /opt/passenger-5.3.7-5.el7.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py:26: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
App 16078 output:   import sys, os, re, imp, threading, signal, traceback, socket, select, struct, logging, errno
App 16078 output: [ pid=16078, time=2020-01-15 16:18:24,002 ]: PyNaCl is not installed, voice will NOT be supported
App 16078 output: [ pid=16078, time=2020-01-15 16:18:24,033 ]: WSGI application raised an exception!
App 16078 output: Traceback (most recent call last):
App 16078 output:   File "/opt/passenger-5.3.7-5.el7.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 199, in main_loop
App 16078 output:     socket_hijacked = self.process_request(env, input_stream, client)
App 16078 output:   File "/opt/passenger-5.3.7-5.el7.cloudlinux/src/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 333, in process_request
App 16078 output:     result = self.app(env, start_response)
App 16078 output:   File "/home/bist1484/virtualenv/bot/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 598, in run
App 16078 output:     return future.result()
App 16078 output:   File "/home/bist1484/virtualenv/bot/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 579, in runner
App 16078 output:     await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
App 16078 output:   File "/home/bist1484/virtualenv/bot/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 542, in start
App 16078 output:     await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
App 16078 output: TypeError: login() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself host my bot on cPanel. I'll help you with hosting your bot. Make sure your bot is in the home directory, **with permissions set to 755**.

You'll need a start script and a stop script. Make a new file in the cgi-bin of your public_html and you'll be able to start the bot at yourmaindomain.com/cgi-bin/startbot.py considering you name the start script to startbot.py. Place the following code in the start script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import os, subprocess, signal

print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")

counter = 0
p = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-u', 'username'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# must match your username --------^^^^^^^^

out, err = p.communicate()
for line in out.splitlines():
  if 'heliobot.py'.encode('utf-8') in line:
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^----- this has to match the filename of your bot script

    counter += 1
    print("Bot already running.")

if counter == 0:
  subprocess.Popen("/home/username/heliobot.py")
#                         ^^^^^^^^-- be sure to update it to your username

  print("Bot started!")
```

For the stop script, you can create a stopbot.py file in the same cgi-bin where you'll be able to stop the bot at yourmaindomain.com/cgi-bin/stopbot.py, place the following code in the script:

```
!/usr/bin/python3.6

import os, subprocess, signal

print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")

counter = 0
p = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-u', 'username'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# must match your username --------^^^^^^^^

out, err = p.communicate()
for line in out.splitlines():
  if 'heliobot.py'.encode('utf-8') in line:
#     ^^^^^^^--- this has to match the filename of your loop

    counter += 1
    pid = int(line.split(None, 1)[0])
    print("Stopping bot.")
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)

if counter == 0:
  print("Already stopped.")
```

**Replace the first line, that's the shebang, with the Python path of your hosting provider. Ensure that the modules used are installed, else request the host to install it for you. Also, ensure that the permissions of all these files are 755, otherwise you'll get Internal Server Errors.**

Do remember to replace those parameters I've highlighted in the scripts. That's exactly how I've been hosting my bot on cPanel free hosting since I started developing. I never had money to get a VPS so this was the best and seemingly the only option for me. (I don't prefer Heroku and other application hosts for a variety of reasons). Hope that helps and solves your problem! If you need help with anything else, just comment it down and I'll try to help you out. :)

Regards,
Sayan Bhattacharyya.

Comment: Thanks for your full answer. What do you mean by setting the permissions to 755?

Comment: The 755 gives permissions for execution which is very important, in order to execute that file and the main bot file which you've made. To edit the permissions > Right click on the file > Click *Change permissions* > And change the permissions as in the below image : https://m.imgur.com/I2GKJUr

Comment: Can you still help me setting up that? I did the scripts, but it doesn't work and I can't know why.

Comment: EDIT: I'm having a `[Errno 8] Exec format error: ` error

Comment: EDIT: Working, but I can't print anything because the window is loading, loading, loading...

Comment: hi. I know this is too late but I did all of that and when I try the url, it downloads my startbot.py not executing it. how do I execute it?

Answer (score 1):

cPanel is designed for web hosting, not for applications like Discord bots.
The application entry point is for [web application frameworks that support WSGI](https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frameworks.html). It does not apply to Discord bots.

Comment: So how should I do to run a discord bot on cPanel? Is it possible?

Comment: No, that's not something cPanel is designed for.

Comment: So for o2switch, if I want to host my bot, I have to use the terminal

Comment: I'm not familiar with o2switch, but again, I believe it's designed for web hosting.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your answer. I have to use terminal instead of using Setup Python App

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`Client.run`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.run).  Specifically, it looks like you need to prepare a partial function that you can pass to this other application:

```
from functools import partial
from discord import Client

client = Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)

runner = partial(client.run, "your token")  # runner() then starts the bot
```

Comment: Yes.  Remember to replace the placeholder with the token for your bot.

Comment: Still don't work. I set a log file but there is no file on the server. It should be because I print something when the bot is running.
I added the token where was the placeholder.